# Mongodb conditional search

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing

I have a mongodb collection on this I have created a text index so that I can search content in it by search terms and I have some 5-6 fields in that index.

The search runs fine but I would like to optimize it further. How can I perform conditional search on my collection which gives me great query optimization?

For example suppose I want to perform a search on the query string `"apple"` but only on those documents where `"type": {$in: ["electronics","fruits"]}]`. These types are dynamically created by code and are bound to increase in number over time.

How can I do it without compromising on the performance?

Answer (score 0):

if you have defined the right indexes, and yoy know that your data are going to grow in terms of recorda and move in terms of content, then you should update your database statistics regularly (in a crontab for instance ).

Comment: what database statistics do you mean? Can u plz elaborate?

Comment: On every dbms, there is a function to update the statistics of a database. It recomputes the paths of the indexes in function of your data at the moment. Therefore, the next queries will be faster because all has been optimized.